# How to assign Tags and retrieve in NSTextfield Using NSTabelview?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tags, nstableview, nstextfield

Here I am assigning tag to NSTextfield this is my bellow code but it is not working, here NoofBadges is NSTextfield object.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
   EventCell *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    cellView.NoofBadges.tag=row;
    cellView.NoofBadges.delegate = self;
}
```

Here I did't recive the NSTextfield Tag values

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
{

NSLog(@"%ld",(long)fieldEditor.tag);
}
```

Comment: What is NSText?  According to the doc, it's a text object like a string.  It doesn't make sense if you want to print the tag of a text object when in fact what you want is the tag of a control.

Comment: @El Tomato when I am NSTextfield editing time - (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
{} this delegate only calling. if u have any solution can u tell me please, I am new in cocoa applications.

Comment: What is the `control` parameter?